# Pass parameter to command from controller Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a command which executes some actions that depend on the entity passed in parameter.

**checkAlertCommand.php:**

```
<?php

namespace MDB\PlatformBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class checkAlertCommand extends Command {

    protected function configure() {
        $this
                ->setName('platform:checkAlert')
                ->setDescription('Check the alert in in function of the current advert')
                ->addArgument(
                        'postedAdvert'
        );
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        $postedAdvert = $input->getArgument('postedAdvert');
        $output->writeln($postedAdvert->getTitre());
    }

}

?>
```

So my questions are:

- How to get an entity as argument in the **checkAlertCommand.php**?
- How to call this command from a controller and pass the desired entity as argument?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass an entity directly to a console command. Instead of you should pass "id" of entity as argument, then use repository and pick up desired entity by its id.

```
<?php

namespace MDB\PlatformBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class checkAlertCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand {

    protected function configure() {
        $this
                ->setName('platform:checkAlert')
                ->setDescription('Check the alert in in function of the current advert')
                ->addArgument(
                        'postedAdvertId'
        );
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        $postedAdvertId = $input->getArgument('postedAdvertId');

        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $repo = $em->getRepository('MDBPlatformBundle:PostedAdvert'); 
        $postedAdvert = $repo->find($postedAdvertId);
        $output->writeln($postedAdvert->getTitre());
    }

}

?>
```

You should use Process component to run the command inside a controller.

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput;
use MDB\PlatformBundle\Command\checkAlertCommand; 

    class MyController extends Controller 
    {
        public function indexAction()
        {
            // get post $postedAdvertId here
            ....
            $command = new checkAlertCommand();
            $command->setContainer($this->container);
            $input = new ArrayInput(array('postedAdvertId' => $postedAdvertId));
            $output = new NullOutput();
            $result = $command->run($input, $output);
             ...
        }
    }
```

**Update: Answer to your question**

I'm not sure what exactly do you mean "asynchronous", but given example executes the command in synchronous way, so mean the controller will wait till command will be finished and only then will go to next operation. But if you need run it in asynchronous(in background) way,you should use Process component http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. And thanks for the info about the fact it's impossible to pass an entity :)

Comment: Just one more question, when i call a command from my controller, is it asynchronous ? Does the command execute in the same time than the rest of the code ?